# How to cross out in editing?

Tags: support, editing

I see some people put a line through a sentence to cross out a sentence.
How to do that?

Comment: You can also look at revision histories to see how people do things.  For example, if a post has been edited, you can click on the time to the right of "edited" at the bottom of the post, then click on "view source".  If the post hasn't been edited, you can manually enter the revision address like this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/1109/revisions but with the number changed to the number of the post you want to see.

Answer (score 4):

Using `<strike>Text</strike>`. Like <strike>this</strike>.

You can find help by clicking the help button during editing

[image]

Comment: Just `<s>` instead of `<strike>` works too.

Comment: How about mathematical expressions? the method no longer works.